# memory leak from d3js javascript

Tags: memory, d3.js, charts

I made chart which is similar with [this chart](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1429426).
when I keep clicking 'make random data' button, browser memory keep increasing.
how should I take this down.

Comment: Does this issue occur in the example as well or only in your chart?

Comment: both have same issue. I just give that chart for test.

Comment: I guess you could try adding an explicit `delete` for the old data when updating.

Comment: Do you actually run out of memory? If not, it's possible (likely, actually) that objects just have not yet been garbage collected.

Comment: Agree with @EthanJewett.  In chrome, I can add a 1000 bars over and over and get my memory usage up to >500m, stop clicking, what 10 seconds, memory usage drops to 50m.